# My VPS provider offers only Ubuntu 18.04 minimal, but I need standard -- is there an easy upgrade path?

Tags: 18.04, vps, ubuntu-minimal, minimal-install

My VPS provider offers various Ubuntu server versions, but only the minimal ones, which I found out when I wasn't able to proceed due to missing package "acl". The provider added it for me, but I'm worried that there will be more important but missing ones that will pop up in the future.

I wonder if there's a way to add the packages needed to bring it to the equivalent of a standard install. Is this something I could do without having to install every missing package, and how would I even know which ones to install?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know. That's why you have apt.

Option 1: Install the `ubuntu-server` package. It will drag in all of the other dependencies.

Option 2: Install the `tasksel` package, and use it to install `ubuntu-server`.

If you REALLY want to know what packages you are missing, simply ask apt: `apt install --simulate ubuntu-server`